# VBA for scraping local Google search suggestions

Tags: xml, excel, vba, user-interface, google-search-api

I am writing a VBA code to scrape the top 10 google search suggestions for a given term. I do so by calling out to this URL:

http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=Search+Term

However, I would like to emulate a variable local search to see the top search suggestions for a US state (or city/zip code if that is possible) that is specified by the end user.

I have tried including '&near=', '&uule=', and '&gr=' with no change in the result. Is there another URL parameter I could use to emulate a local search?

Answer (score 0):

I've got same speciefic task with SERP retriving using local search. [There is an article](https://moz.com/ugc/geolocation-the-ultimate-tip-to-emulate-local-search) with some sort of investigation showing that Google wants `UULE` parameter that points to geolocation. It coded as it follows below.

`"w+CAIQICI" + Base64Encode(canonicalString)`

Also `canonicalString` as canonical name of requested geolocation you can get from [Google geocoder API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro). Some [related example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158492/code-to-get-gps-coordinates-from-address-vb6-vba-vbscript) found here.